# Excel - VBA Check if the sheet exists, if so change first empty cell from range

Tags: vba, excel

My below code should create copies of CMR sheet based on values in Data sheet, column A, then copy values from row to specific cells of CMR copy(cell indexes are stated as header of table in Data sheet).

The code do the copies, name them based on values and also add data to specific cells of CMR copies. The problem is when I have more rows related to one CMR copy no. (e.g. 592): if the CMR copy already exist the code should add data to next empty cell from range C38:C50.

I tried at least if-else statement but for existing sheets it is not working correctly. e.g. if sheet named "592" already exists it is still making copies named Sheet(x). Probably ExistingSh is always nothing. Could you please help?

Also I am not sure how could I change else statement when I want to add value to first empty cell from range C38:C50, not directly to C38.

Thank you, all your help is appreciated.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEkUa.jpg)

Sub CreateCMR()

```
Dim ListSh As Worksheet, BaseSh As Worksheet
Dim NewSh As Worksheet
Dim ExistingSh As Worksheet
Dim ListOfNames As Range, LRow As Long, Cell As Range
Dim counter As Integer


With ThisWorkbook
    Set ListSh = .Sheets("Data")
    Set BaseSh = .Sheets("CMR")
End With

LRow = ListSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set ListOfNames = ListSh.Range("A2:A" & LRow)
counter = 2


For Each Cell In ListOfNames
    Set ExistingSh = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ExistingSh = Worksheets(Cell.Value)

    If ExistingSh Is Nothing Then

        BaseSh.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Set NewSh = ActiveSheet

        With NewSh
            .Name = Cell.Value
        End With

        NewSh.Cells(2, 34) = Worksheets("Template2").Cells(counter, 3)

    Else

        Set ExistingSh = ActiveSheet

        ExistingSh.Cells(38, 3) = Worksheets("Template2").Cells(counter, 16)

    End If
    On Error Goto 0

    counter = counter + 1
Next Cell

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

ListSh.Activate
MsgBox "Done"
```

End Sub

Comment: Quick note, you also need to qualify the `Rows.Count` with the sheet you want to run that on, otherwise it'll run on the ActiveSheet, whatever that may be.

Comment: Get rid of `On Error Resume Next` and see if it's giving you an error somewhere. Then, go read up on OERN and why it has about 2 useful situations and about 7 bajillion non-useful ones.

Comment: The [evils of OERN](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/5411/error-handling#t=201703072025172311117)

Comment: Where is the "Data" sheet?

Comment: It was renamed  - before Template 2, I see I have not changed statements below but before everywhere Template2 was stated, this is not the problem.